# API Quota exceeded

Tags: api, foursquare

In the documentation we can find that `The limits are based on a moving window that tracks the number of requests you send per hour.` (https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits) but in the practice my rate limit isn't recharged even if I wait several minutes.

What happened? Did they change the implementation of API rate limits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The window should still update be updating in real time.

To be clear, if your rate limit is 500, at 11:00, you send 5 requests, the X-RateLimit-Remaining will be 495. If you wait a few minutes to 11:05, and send another request, X-Rate-Limit remaining will be 494 -- it won't have reset yet.

It's not until 12:01 that you'll get back the 5 requests that you'd made at 11:00. So, if you request again at 12:01, your limit would be 498 (-1 for the request you just did, -1 for the 11:05 request). Requesting again at 12:06, and you'll be back up to 499 (the full limit, minus what you just used).

Comment: Is it possible to query for `X-RateLimit-Remaining`? I know that I could make a dummy request and check its response header, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I don't believe so -- I think we only send this information down in the HTTP headers.