# Is there a way to check the Foursquare venue rate-limit without actually costing a request?

Tags: api, foursquare

I am currently pinging the foursquare venue platform in order to harmonize my company's data with foursquare's.  Information on the venue harmonization is here: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/mapping

The rate limit is in the headers as X_RATELIMIT_REMAINING. I have a producer pushing out new requests and a consumer which touches the foursquare api.  I would like to find out a way to have the producer check the rate limit without spending the remaining requests.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "dummy" enpoint to check your ratelimit. They have a multi endpoint   but as far as I can remember they'll count each requests inside the batch.

You can count the ratelimit on your side. Here is an explanation :

> The window should still update be updating in real time.
>
> To be clear, if your rate limit is 500, at 11:00, you send 5 requests,
> the X-RateLimit-Remaining will be 495. If you wait a few minutes to
> 11:05, and send another request, X-Rate-Limit remaining will be 494 --
> it won't have reset yet.
>
> It's not until 12:01 that you'll get back the 5 requests that you'd
> made at 11:00. So, if you request again at 12:01, your limit would be
> 498 (-1 for the request you just did, -1 for the 11:05 request).
>
> Requesting again at 12:06, and you'll be back up to 499 (the full
> limit, minus what you just used).

from this thread : [API Quota exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196329/api-quota-exceeded)

If you reproduce this logic and count each request you make per endpoint, you can guess your ratelimit. I'm sorry there is not an easier way to do this :(

Comment: Hah, holy crap that was interesting.   I have been checking the headers from my consumers, but I was hoping to make my producers sleep with no extra cost.  Oh well.  Thanks.